# Can't view/change input field in iframe on phonegap app

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, iframe, pandadoc

So here's the situation.  I am using a third party digital document signing service called PandaDoc in my mobile application which is built on PhoneGap/Cordova and I am not able to change any of the input, text-type fields when attempting to do this via the mobile app on an iPhone (haven't tested Android yet).

Here are some things i noted about this:

1) When viewed online in Chrome (on my laptop) or on my phone in the Chrome browser everything works fine.

2) The only form elements that aren't working on mobile are the input (type=text) ones.  The checkboxes work, the dropdowns work etc...

3) I don't know much about Angular.js but i can tell this third party app was built on it.  When i inspect and compare the mobile vs web version i noticed that on the mobile version the input fields have these two directives:

```
ng-pristine and ng-touched
```

From what i can tell researching these, they seem to be mutually exclusive so not sure how that would affect things.  Also the web version had:

```
ng-dirty and ng-valid-parse
```

both of which the mobile version did not have.

I know it would be best if i could post some code here but i don't know where to start.  In my app there is just a simple embed script that puts the PandaDoc into an iFrame.

If you want to see the mobile test version of this app you can view it at http://dev.velexo.com/m2  I have a test user with a username of "mobile2" and the password is "pass".  Unfortunately there is no easy way to send out the iphone app version of this and that is where the problem is.

Oh also, when you log into the application, click on the W9 Information button and then the Enter Your W9 button, this is what brings up the pandadoc

Also should have mentioned I'm using JQuery Mobile in the app.

Any advice/guidance would be welcome even if it's just a guess.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using ? Does the keyboard open ?

Comment: It's version 9.3.4 and the keyboard does open.  I'm starting to think it's something buggy in the third party application because there are other issues as well.  for example, sometimes when i tap an input field to update it, the thing randomly jumps to another input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just looking over my old questions here.  The answer to the actual question I asked is that you can not change anything in an iFrame from the parent frame unless both the domain and the port match due to the cross-domain policy restraints.

There are no ways around this that I am aware of.

The solution to my particular problem was to get rid of PandaDoc entirely because it just wasn't designed to be used on a mobile device.  In the end i wrote my own javascript for creating a signature and passing to the backend where i used a php pdf generating library to construct the final document.